# getBundleContext method is undefined issue

Tags: java, frameworks, osgi

I'm trying to setup an application that runs on OSGi internally and have tried using the tutorial [here](http://njbartlett.name/2011/07/03/embedding-osgi.html), but I get the error "The method getBundleContext() is undefined for the type Framework" all the time.  As far as I can tell, I'm using the right library, but it's not specified in the mentioned article, so I'm not 100% sure.  I've also tried the examples on Apache's website, [here](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-launching-and-embedding.html), which results in the same issue.  Code below:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ServiceLoader;

import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleException;
import org.osgi.framework.launch.Framework;
import org.osgi.framework.launch.FrameworkFactory;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws BundleException {
        FrameworkFactory frameworkFactory = ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class).iterator().next();
        Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Framework framework = frameworkFactory.newFramework(config);
        framework.start();

        // Throws error that it cannot find method getBundleContext()
        BundleContext context = framework.getBundleContext();
        List<Bundle> installedBundles = new LinkedList<Bundle>();

        installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:org.apache.felix.shell-1.4.2.jar"));
        installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:org.apache.felix.shell.tui-1.4.1.jar"));

        for (Bundle bundle : installedBundles) {
            bundle.start();
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing that makes sense is that either I'm using the wrong libraries, or the libraries have changed and the method I'm attempting to call has since been deprecated out in the last 4 years.  Anyone know how I can fix this?

I doubt it makes much of a difference, but in case it does, I'm using Bndtools for Eclipse to create this project.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  Apparently, the import of `osgi.core` that was in the Bndtools' project build path was out of date, preventing the code from accessing the correct version of the framework libraries.  Updating that fixed the issue.

Additional side-note; Since I'm using Bndtools, I was adding this to the project build path via the bnd.bnd file's build tab.  This, however, was not grabbing the correct version of `osgi.core`, so I had to go under source and add the `version=latest` in order to force it to get the latest version available, so the line now appears as: `osgi.core;version=latest` where it was previously just `osgi.core` under the `-buildpath:` section.

Comment: It's probably unwise to have two versions of a library on your build path anyway.

Comment: Yep, it was a simple mistake that I had missed.  They also had different names on the file, so I overlooked it at first.  The Bndtools version was called `osgi.core` where the newer one was actually named `org.apache.felix.framework`.

Comment: That's not just a different name, it's a different library, it just has overlapping contents. The Felix one is an OSGi implementation whereas `osgi.core` is the pure API published by the OSGi Alliance. I strongly recommend building against `osgi.core`... you just need to get the right version of it.

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks for the tip.  I'll look for an updated version of it and replace the felix library with the core library, again.  Also editing my answer in case someone else sees this due to a similar encounter with this issue and doesn't read the comments.  I've still got a lot to learn about OSGi, but I'm having fun with it now, as things are starting to take shape much quicker than they were back when all I knew was what it did, and not how it did it.  Ahh, the joys of self teaching...